# Counting Hamiltonian cycles in $n \times n$ square grid

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, stochastic-processes, discrete-geometry

I wonder if anyone has counted these curves, either exactly or asymptotically?

Let $S_n$ be an $n \times n$ subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ consisting of $n^2$
lattice points: a *lattice square*. 
Define a *rectilinear filler curve* for $S_n$ to be a simple closed
curve that passes through each of the $n^2$ lattice points,
and is composed entirely of vertical and horizontal edges.
So the curve is what is called a "rectilinear" or "orthogonal" polygon in the literature. Every turn of such a curve is $\pm 90^\circ$.

I'd like to know the number $f(n)$ of distinct filler curves for $S_n$,
distinct up to rotations and reflections. So if $C_1$ can be rotated
and/or reflected to lay on top of $C_2$, then $C_1$ and $C_2$ are not distinct.

$f(2) = 1$, and $f(4) = 2$:

---

[image: Filler4x4]

---

$f(n)=0$ when $n$ is odd, as can be seen as follows.
View a filler curve $C$ as composed of unit-length segments
connecting lattice points;
call these the *edges* of $C$ (so two incident edges can be collinear).
Each horizontal line $y = m + \frac{1}{2}$ for $m$ an integer
crosses an even number of edges of $C$; similarly for vertical lines. 
So the total number of edges $E$ of $C$ is even. 
In Euler's relation $V-E+F=2$,
$F=2$ (interior & exterior of $C$). So $V=E$. So $V$ must be even.
But $V=n^2$ for $n$ odd is odd.

Already I don't know what is $f(6)$. It is easy to see the
growth of $f$ is exponential in $n$, but I don't know more.
In particular, I do not see how to recursively connect $f(n)$ to $f(n-2)$.

---

[image: FIller6x6]

---

Comment: See "UST =(Uniform Spanning Tree) Peano Curve": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RQmLNa5ZNo

Comment: These are studied in the context of Schramm-Loewner evolution (SLE). See e.g. Figure 9.2 of http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v161-n2-p07.pdf. The point is that SLE has three qualitative regimes based on its parameter $\kappa$. The last regime, with $\kappa/geq 8$, is where it is a space-filling curve. These discrete Peano curves are conjectured (I believe it is still a conjecture) to limit to SLE with $\kappa=8$.

Comment: But in terms of *counting* these, I believe it amounts to counting spanning trees on a grid (which I think should be known). This is because these curves "go between" a tree and dual tree. See pages 8-9 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0112234.pdf for more details.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Thanks for the references. It seems my rectilinear filler curves are known in the physics literature as "Hamiltonian paths on the Manhattan lattice."

Comment: So in thinking about it more, I don't think you get all Hamiltonian cycles from trees in the way I described. Counting these cycles may be hard. But maybe the tree model gives you the right asymptotics.

Comment: These are Hamiltonian cycles on the $2n \times 2n$ square grid. Their numbers are tabulated as http://oeis.org/A003763. The asymptotics should be known to people dealing with self-awoiding walks (SAW).

Comment: By the way, a simpler argument for showing that there are no Hamiltonian cycles in the odd case is by coloring vertices black and white in chessboard manner and noting that the colors alternate along the cycle. Or, in other words, a bipartite graph with parts of different sizes is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: From @IvanIzmestiev's link: Also known as "closed rook tours."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The asymptotics of the number of Hamiltonian paths from one corner to the opposite (they exist only for $n$ odd) is $\tau^{n^2}$, where $\tau$ is not known exactly but satisfies $1.429 < \tau < 1.530$:

*Bousquet-Mélou, M.; Guttmann, A. J.; Jensen, I.*, [**Self-avoiding walks crossing a square**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/38/42/001), J. Phys. A, Math. Gen. 38, No. 42, 9159-9181 (2005). [ZBL1078.82009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1078.82009).

One can transform a path or cycle on $n \times n$ grid into a cycle or path on $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ grid, see figure. It follows that the number of cycles on $n \times n$ grid is between $\tau^{(n-1)^2}$ and $\tau^{(n+1)^2}$, and in any case between $1.429^{n^2}$ and $1.53^{n^2}$.

[image]

Wikipedia knows more about [self-avoiding walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk).

Comment: Thank you, Ivan! Mod'ing out the rotations and reflections might not be easy, but your answer and the OEIS entry you cited bring me close enough.

Comment: Oh, I have overlooked that you are counting up to symmetries. Asymptotically it changes nothing. And an algorithm for computation (as well as values for small $n$) can be found in https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0545.

Comment: Oh, perfect!: "Enumeration of nonisomorphic Hamiltonian cycles on square grid graphs." Ed Wynn. I *think* his results imply $f(6)=28$, but this needs further study.

Comment: See @AndrásSalamon's correction: $f(6)=149$.

Comment: I agree with András's correction -- and http://oeis.org/A209077 credits Jon Wild for finding the 149 solutions in 2011.

Comment: Also, I agree with Ivan that removing symmetrical duplicates does not change the asymptotics. In fact, the number of symmetrical solutions appears to be very much smaller than that of asymmetric solutions -- maybe the former is roughly the square root of the latter (based on the values for n<=10), which is a large factor.

Comment: However, it seems to me that the number of cycles that Ivan mentions is incomplete -- most solutions do not have straight edges on the base and right side. The number of ways to weave in and out of the corner-to-corner path will increase with n, but the details (for example, avoiding the creation of distinct loops) seem rather difficult to predict.

Comment: @EdWynn: this was not intended to be a bijection, but only an injections from Hamiltonian paths on $n \times n$ to Hamiltonian cycles on $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ and a similar injection from cycles to paths.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev: So (to check I understand), when you wrote "the number of cycles is...", this referred to the number of these special cycles?  And this gives us a lower bound on the number of cycles in total. If the true total is larger by a factor as large as 2^n, then the bound still captures the asymptotic growth. I think I understand -- thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @EdWynn: I mean the number of all cycles on a $n \times n$ grid. It is bigger than the number of paths on $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ grid and smaller than the number of paths on $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ grid, hence the asymptotics.

Answer (score 3):

This is a summary of the sprawling comments above.

This is OEIS sequence http://oeis.org/A209077 (number of isomorphism classes of Hamiltonian circuits on $2n \times 2n$ grid).
Ed Wynn discussed a method of computing these in https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0545 and extended the known values from $1 \le n \le 4$ to $1 \le n \le 10$.

In particular, for the 6 by 6 grid (where $n=3$) which was asked about in the question, there are 149 of these circuits up to reflections and rotations.